# How to "close" a JMenu in an Event Handler - Java

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, jmenu

I have a simple MouseAdapter that I add to a JMenu. I want the menu to show its contents when moused over, react when clicked on, and hide its contents when the mouse leaves it. Here's where I add the listener:

```
      public final void addGuiReaction(Runnable clickReaction) {
            JMenu THIS = this;
            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                final Runnable reaction = clickReaction;
                final JMenu source = THIS;
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {reaction.run();}
                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {source.doClick();} // Opens the menu
                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {/* Need to "close" the menu */}
            });
      }
```

This works just fine for both the *reaction* and the *open when moused over* functionality, but I can't figure out how to close it. Tried both *setSelected(false)* and *setPopupMenuVisible(false)* but the issue with both is that the menu doesn't open again the next time I mouse over it.

Anyone knows a nice way of closing the menu?

Comment: The normal use of JMenu is not to program how to open or close, but to react on the ItemEvents that the menu invoke `ActionEvent` and  `ItemEvent`. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html
So you normally do not need to programm the UI, because you are using a UI-component.
There is no need to "close" the menu.

Comment: @TobiasOtto You cannot add an ActionListener to a JMenu (only JMenuItem) and the ItemListener cannot tell the difference between a click and a mouse-over. I want to show the menu by a mouse-over and trigger other functionality by clicking it. So far using a MouseListener has been the closest to what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to "How to close the JMenu..."

In place of this:

```
/* Need to "close" the menu */
```

You can put this:

```
source.dispatchEvent(new KeyEvent(source, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, 0, 0, KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE));
```

Hence simulate the ESC key press which will trigger the respective Action from the ActionMap of the JMenuBar.

However this will not fully solve your problem as while the keyboard arrow keys will work, you will not be able to use the mouse to select any of the items of the JMenu as trying to enter any of them will trigger the JMenu mouseExited event. You may need to attach a proper mouse event listener to the menu items as well.